# Why does the introduced part-title in letter appear twice?

Tags: sectioning, pdftex

My intention is to create a letter with multiple appendixes, which are `\include`d and their `part`-titles will be added to the `\encl`-list.

My letter looks like:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{part}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\part}{\@startsection{part}{-1}{\z@}% name, ebene, einzug
                           {1ex}% vor-abst
                           {1ex}% nach-abst
                           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}\\% format
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Anlage \Alph{part}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{to somebody}
\opening{Dear Sirs and Madams,}
...
\closing{Farewell,}

\include{anlage-a}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The appendix starts as follows:

```
\part{test part}

My part-content...
```

Which gets rendered to:

[image: The title-caption appears twice]

Why does this happen, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `\partmark`. Every sectioning command should have an accompanying `\<level>mark` command that's issued as part of the working of `\@startsection`.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcounter{part}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\part}{\@startsection{part}{-1}{\z@}% name, ebene, einzug
                           {1ex}% vor-abst
                           {1ex}% nach-abst
                           {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{Anlage \Alph{part}}
\newcommand{\partmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{to somebody}
\opening{Dear Sirs and Madams,}
...
\closing{Farewell,}

\part{ABC}

Text

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I bet you want `\input` and not `\include`.

[image]

Comment: You made my day - i haven't found any reference on the `\***mark`-command - even my LaTeX book is not mentioning it. I used `include` to let the appendices appear in the pagestyle of the letter (with header/footer). But i'll probably change that - thanks for the help and your hint! :D

Comment: @florianb You find that in `source2e.pdf`, the commented source of LaTeX

Comment: @ereg - i am so thankful! That's the reference i was looking for!