# latex sectioning below subparagraph

Tags: sectioning, documentclass-writing

I am trying to create a latex class that allows sectioning below subparagraph. For doing that, I modified the `article.cls` class of the texlive distribution adding two more options `\thesubsubsubsection` and `\thesubsubsubsubsection`. So now, the sectioning tree goes as follows:

```
\thesection  
\thesubsection  
\thesubsubsection  
\thesubsubsubsection  
\thesubsubsubsubsection
\theparagraph  
\thesubparagraph
```

Please see below `myarticle.cls`, `mysectioning.tex` and the resulting `mysectioning.pdf`.

I achieved the wanted effects in terms of numbering, table of contents and section formatting. The only problem that I have is that in the new two headings, `\thesubsubsubsection` and `\thesubsubsubsubsection`, the heading title is repeated in the following paragraph as indented text (see Sections 1.1.1.1  and 1.1.1.1.1 below).

Do you know how can I avoid this behavior?

Many thanks in advance for your help and ideas!
Sebastian

[myarticle.cls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlKAKruORFiR25nSlkyM01uZzQ/view?usp=sharing)

[mysectioning.tex](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlKAKruORFib0g0VWFfWVJkbUU/view?usp=sharing)

[mysectioning.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlKAKruORFiZkRBbFgzUi1EcmM/view?usp=sharing)

[image: myarticle PDF document]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duplicate of the title stem from a call to do something with the sectional *mark*. That is, each numbered sectional unit `\<section>` has an associated `\<section>mark` that is used for printing content to the header/footer. The [LaTeX kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) defines these, not the class, as

```
\let\sectionmark\@gobble
\let\subsectionmark\@gobble
\let\subsubsectionmark\@gobble
\let\paragraphmark\@gobble
\let\subparagraphmark\@gobble
```

This way they all do *nothing* (they `\@gobble` their argument) but they're defined. As such, you need to add

```
\let\subsubsubsectionmark\@gobble
\let\subsubsubsubsectionmark\@gobble
```

within the class file somewhere so they are at least defined.

You may wonder why there is no error reported since there is a call made to the undefined marks...? That's because they're called via a `c`ontrol `s`equence construction using

```
\csname <section>mark\endcsname
```

Here's an extraction of `\@sect` - called by [`\@startsection`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764) when you execute a generic sectional unit that should be numbered:

```
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}% <=================== Call the sectional unit mark
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
```

The highlighted macro shows the call to the mark. This type of call doesn't report errors if the control sequence is not known.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the detailed explanation of the reasons! I just copied the two `\@gobble` lines into [myarticle.cls](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlKAKruORFiRG5oaEowaFdXQzQ/view?usp=sharing) and I got the desired effects [mysectioning.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlKAKruORFiSDNxeVpfZlUwMnM/view?usp=sharing). Very easy/elegant solution after digging into the Latex Kernel. And great didactic exposition! Thanks a lot Werner!

Comment: While I might agree that the duplicate I pointed to can be debatable, this is certainly a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241351/why-does-the-introduced-part-title-in-letter-appear-twice

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. The first one wasn't, but the new one is.